# Solving a trig. equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Solve for x $$\tan 2x = 3 \tan x$$

Well, I'm stuck with this one. This is how far I got.

$$\tan 2x = 3 \tan x$$

$$\frac{2 \tan x}{1 - \tan^2 x} = 3 \tan x$$

$$2 \tan x = 3 \tan x - 3 \tan^3 x$$

$$3 \tan^3 x = \tan x$$

$$3 \tan^3 x - \tan x = 0$$

$$\tan x (3 \tan^2 x - 1) = 0$$

So, then a part of the solution is $\tan x = 0$, so $x = k\pi$

This leaves $\tan^2x = 1$. I thought to take the root of both sides, leaving me with $\tan x = 1$. So I figured $x = \frac{1}{4}\pi + k\pi$ so we the first and third quadrants, where the tangent is positive.

But, to my deep deep sadness, this last part turned out to be wrong.

What am I missing here?

Comment: if $tan^2x=1$, $tan2x$ is not defined

Comment: yeah, I had just noticed, and now im updating

Comment: @Apeiron So then this leaves $\tan^2 x=\frac{1}{3}$, i.e. $\tan x=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Even if it were $\tan^2 x-1$, you'd get $\tan x=\pm 1$, not just $\tan x =1$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The equation $3\tan^3 x - \tan x = 0$ factors as $\tan x(\color{red}{3}\tan^2 x - 1) = 0$ (you forgot the $3$).

Hence, $\tan x = 0$ or $\tan x = \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Both of these should be easy to solve.